# How to get both obj value and keys to build array object for POST method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having an a problem with the data I'm trying to build, the scenario is that if user only input `Id` or `ProductName` then only use that or if user input `Id` and `product Name` then use both.

At the moment my JSON is only taking one of these but not both.

Input using `ID or Name` works fine, expected result is: --

```
{
"Filters": {

    "complex_filterField": [
      {
        "keyField": "name",
        "valueField": {
          "keyField": "like",
          "valueField": "%aviator%"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and if both Id and Name inputs are populated then expected result is like the code below, which i'm having trouble with building.

Question is how can I take both values in build it like below?

```
{
  "Filters": {

    "complex_filterField": [
      {
        "keyField": "name",
        "valueField": {
          "keyField": "like",
          "valueField": "%aviator%"
        }
      },
      {
        "keyField": "product_id",
        "valueField": {
          "keyField": "like",
          "valueField": "15%"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Sample working code](https://jsfiddle.net/otrqmg17/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over your fields, but then overwriting the `query` each iteration - so you just end up with whichever was last.

A simple refactor:

```js
function LoginController($scope) {

    $scope.search = function (param) {
      var queryArray = [];
      for (var keyName in param) {
          if (param[keyName] != undefined && param[keyName] != '' && param[keyName] != null) {
              var queryValue = param[keyName];
              var queryLabel = keyName;
              var query = {
                "keyField": queryLabel,
                "valueField": {
                    "keyField": "like",
                    "valueField": '%' + queryValue + '%'
              }}
              queryArray.push(query);
          }
      }

      var searchData = {
                  "Filters": {
                      "complex_filterField": queryArray
                  }
              }

       console.log('searchData: ', searchData);
                
                
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input ng-model="param.id" placeholder="id"></input>
    <input ng-model="param.itemName" placeholder="item name"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="search(param)" value="Login"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="login in logins">{{ login }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heh fixed it before I saw your answer, funny that we have the same `var queryArray`